# Delete Stored Procedure through remote

Tags: java, t-sql, stored-procedures, sql-server-2000, junit4

I am creating and testing a stored procedure through remote using JUnit , my user name is test and this is my code,

```
String sql = "create procedure test.firstProc3 AS select GETDATE()";
cursor.execute(sql);
cursor.executeQuery("firstProc3");
```

ANd to drop the procedure:

```
String dropSQL = "DROP PROCEDURE test.firstProc3";
cursor.execute(dropSQL);
```

Since the Drop Procedure is not working, I am unable to run the same SP for the second time ( new session) My error is:

There is already an object named 'firstProc3' in the database.

When I gave **sp_help** on the server side,
the table had the row with the value

**firstProc3 test stored procedure**

However when I give 
DROP PROCEDURE test.firstProc3 in the Query analyzer, the row is getting deleted from the table.

What could be the issue in trying to do the same operation through Junit?

Are there any permissions to be set?

PS - the user test has the db_ddladmin enabled.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I managed to finally solve the problem by using the following :

```
declare @object_id int
select @object_id = object_id('test.firstProc5')
EXEC sp_MSdrop_object @object_id
GO
```

This is removing the data from the table too.And I am able to successfully run the Testcase multiple times !

Thanks for your help :)

The link I referred to is here, hope it helps someone:

http://www.mssqlcity.com/Articles/Undoc/SQL2000UndocSP.htm

Answer (score 0):

Based upon the error message, I doubt it is a permissions issue. It looks like your cursor object is running the create again when you're trying to drop, or you're never really dropping the proc before running your unit test again, or the tests are running out of logical order in some fashion. Can you instantiate a new cursor object and try the drop with that, or verify the SQL being run against the database using [profiler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa173918%28v=sql.80%29.aspx) or some debug output?

Beyond that, I would be curious to see if changing your SQL commands to check for proc existence makes the error go away (not that this is the right answer):

```
if object_id('test.firstProc3') is null begin
    -- Dynamic SQL because create must be first in a batch
    exec ('create procedure test.firstProc3 as select getdate()') 
end

if object_id('test.firstProc3') is not null begin
    drop procedure test.firstProc3
end
```

Comment: Hello,Its working now, I changed the drop procedure to :`code`"cursor.parse("drop procedure firstProc3");
cursor.execute();"`code`.  Thanks :)

Comment: Sorry, I spoke tooo soon. ITs failing again. i will try out the profiler and let you know. IS there anyway to grant a DROP permission to the user thorugh the code?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something small, and maybe it is even not the case, but have you tried to use escaping in your drop statement?

something like

```
drop procedure [test].[firstProc3]
```

I can remember that i had an issue with this when i called a drop table from c# code...

Comment: Hello, I got it to work using the following code EXEC           MSdrop_object @object_id